# Spring Data Neo4J - Create new nodes via REST endpoint

Tags: neo4j, spring-data

Does Spring Data provide a way to create new nodes via a REST endpoint? I don't think so but would like to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you referring to?

SDN works in both versions also with Neo4j server but using the Cypher Endpoint under the hood.

Comment: I am using Spring Data Neo4J version 4.0.0.RELEASE.  What would be an example of a Spring URL used to create a new entity? I know that the Cypher endpoint is http://localhost:7474/db/data/node.